# Call java method with JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I developed a message system and in the inbox I want to delete multiple messages selecting it with some checks and calling the delete method but I don't know if I can do it witout a form. Some people tells me that I can do with JQuery but I don't know how to do.

**MessagesController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mensajes/delete/{menssageId}")
    public String menssagesDelete(final ModelMap model, @PathVariable("menssageId") final Integer mensajeId,
        final HttpServletRequest request, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {

        final User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute(Constantes.SESSION_USER_KEY);

        final Mensajes mensaje = this.mensajesService.loadMensaje(mensajeId);

        this.mensajesService.deleteMensaje(mensaje);

        return "redirect:/menssages/home";
    }
```

EDIT:

Now I have this:

**MessagesController.java**

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mensajes/deleteMensajes.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public void deleteMensajes(final String[] arrayMensajes) {

    }
```

And this is de js code:

```
function eliminarMensajes(){
    var arrayMensajesSeleccionados = jQuery('[name="msgIdRecibido"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    //Llamada ajax 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "deleteMensajes.json",
        data:{'arrayMensajes': arrayMensajesSeleccionados},
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("hola");
        }
    });
```

When enter the controller method the `arrayMensajes` is null What Im doing wrong?

Comment: `ajax` is your friend.

Comment: you should look at the jquery ajax!

Comment: @zeitgeist Can show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when add this to controller

```
public void deleteMensajes(@RequestParam(value="arrayMensajes[]", required=false) final String[] arrayMensajes)
```

Comment: this works because you have to pass parameter name here. Since you are passing it in arrayMensajes, you should get values using that. Read on http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html